# Masking a specific element of 1D tensor before reduce

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to know how best to reduce_sum a 1D tensor, avoiding a specific element identified by index.  The index is a result of an argmin on another vector.

In numpy I can do:

```
to_ignore = np.argmin(some_vector)
x[to_ignore] = 0.
result = np.sum(x)
```

However, in TF it seems not possible to "zero-out" a specific element of a tensor, so the above code won't work.  In principle

```
to_ignore = tf.argmin(some_tensor)
x = tf.boolean_mask(x, tf.not_equal(tf.range(some_tensor.shape[0]),
                                    initial_event))
result = tf.reduce_sum(x)
```

seems a very inefficient solution, and I've not got it to work given the dynamic nature of `some_tensor.shape[0]`.

This seems like a simple thing to achieve, I wonder if I'm missing something?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I'm not sure `tf.boolan_mask` should be "inefficient", although if you don't like that approach you can also take the result of `tf.not_equal`, cast it to `x.dtype` and multiply it with `x` before summing.

Comment: Thanks jdehesa.  I guess coming from a C++ background, I'm slightly frustrated by the functional approach to programming here -- life seems much more efficient if all you do is update x[to_ignore] (e.g. *(x+to_ignore) = 0).